# How to avoid Security messages / security alerts from IE

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

We are getting security message like this while executing url:

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate.   The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.     We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.     Click here to close this webpage.     Continue to this website (not recommended).
>            More information

Same type of security alerts with message like this

> This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses security rish, DO you want to continue?

How to avoid them through code either javascript, jsp or any way. We can not ask each user to modify their internet options. Please let me know if there is any solutions for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's browser behavior that you can't and shouldn't be allowed to modify using JavaScript, or anything else for that matter. In fact, these security alerts are there to warn the user that something is (potentially) wrong. If you could disable them, there would be no point in having them, right?

Fix whatever problems you have with the security certificate and you'll be fine. I'll guess here that your certificates are self-signed - buy one. They are not that expensive.

Comment: Can you provide any link to get additional information on Certificates?

Comment: @vishnu There are many companies that sell them, like [verisign](http://www.verisign.com/) or [thwate](http://www.thawte.com/)

Comment: This certificates only for **https**? When i contacted them they are saying these for https. But my application url is http. Can i use them any way? Can i avoid these alerts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a current, valid certificate on your web server.

Comment: How do i know current, valid certificate on my web server

Answer (score 0):

[There is a problem with this website's security certificate](http://www.thereisaproblemwiththiswebsitessecuritycertificate.com) could mean you need to check that the clock is set correctly.

Comment: Not in this case. The message is explicit that the root is untrusted, not that it's "Expired or not yet valid."

Answer (score 0):

Host all content on an https website. not an http one. You do not need a certificate then.

Comment: Google sites is https so if any non https content is used it will pull that warning up. There are many workarounds out there that are free. If you buy a certificate it will make your http turn into https but if you host any http content (posting content from a http website) you will still get the warning even with a secure site certificate.

Answer (score 0):

1> *The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.*

This message indicates that the page is using a HTTPS-based resource which has a certificate which does not chain to a globally trusted root certificate. If you don't know what resources/URLS are causing this, open the F12 Developer Tools and look at the Console tab, or run Fiddler and watch for the warning popup.

2> *This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses security risk, DO you want to continue?*

This message is shown when you attempt to use an XMLHTTPRequest object to request data from a cross-domain location (e.g. www.domain.com tries to grab data from domain.com). That operation is a violation of [Same-Origin-Policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx).

By default in IE, this is **blocked**, but inside the Intranet Zone, this feature is set to **Prompt** and thus you see this message instead.

To fix this, either change the request URL so that it does not go to a different domain, or use XDomainRequest, or use a serverside proxy page to make the cross-origin data request from the server rather than the client.